# Google multiple form response to a common master sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I have three Google forms, all have common fields. I need to submit responses from all three form to a common sheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google forms only allow one linked form per sheet, but you can have a document with multiple tabs by [changing the form's response destination](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2917686?hl=en).

There are a few ways to get around this.

You could have one document with 4 tabs, one for each form's response and another 'master' tab which uses an array formula to combine the responses, eg:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(FormOneResponses!A2:D ; FormTwoResponses!A2:D ; FormThreeResponses!A2:D)
```

This assumes that all of the forms have exactly the same fields in the same order, if this isn't the case you would need to either reorder the columns or use several array formulas. You can also use functions like 'SORT' and 'UNIQUE' on this data.

You could also store the data in the forms, then use google apps script's [Form.getValues(timestamp) function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) at time intervals to grab the responses for each form, put them in the order you want and add to the end of a single spreadsheet.

Another way to do this would be to create three web forms (possibly with [google apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)) and have all three append rows to the same sheet when the data is submitted.

Comment: Thank you, for prompt answer, all the ways are good, how to work on when sheets are in different files

Comment: importranges in a single cell separated by commas will import and append all sheets in a single one.

Comment: Trying `ARRAYFORMULA` as above, getting wrong # arguments: `Wrong number of arguments to ARRAYFORMULA. Expected 1 arguments, but got 2 arguments.` -- then trying `IMPORTRANGE` and getting `Import Internal Error.`